# How do I lowercase a nested struct name when using json.marshal?

Tags: json, go

I'm exposing a REST endpoint with some data. It's a struct, say:

```
type status struct {
    Config struct {
        Allow   bool `json:"allow"`
        Expired bool `json:"expired"`
    }
    Database struct {
        Healthy          bool   `json:"healthy"`
        WaitCount        int64  `json:"wait_count"`
    }
}
```

I'm using the json tag to denote how a struct field should look when calling the endpoint. Using the above, I'm getting the following payload as response:

```
{
    "Config": {
        "allow": false,
        "expired": false,
    },
    "Database": {
        "healthy": true,
        "wait_count": 1,
    },
}
```

I'd like for `Config` and `Database` to be lowercase, meaning `config` and `database`. However, changing them to that in the Go code means the `"encoding/json"` package cannot "see" them as they aren't exported outside of the package scope.

How do I lowercase the nested struct's in the json response payload?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nested struct is a field in the containing struct. Add a field tags as you did with the other fields:

```
type status struct {
    Config struct {
        Allow   bool `json:"allow"`
        Expired bool `json:"expired"`
    } `json:"config"` // <-- add tag here ...
    Database struct {
        Healthy          bool   `json:"healthy"`
        WaitCount        int64  `json:"wait_count"`
    } `json:"database"` // <-- ... and here
}
```